# AWS Custom Lambda Authorizer: Allow and Deny based on the URL parameters with the same leading URL

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

I'm am writing my own AWS Custom Lambda Authorizer for the AWS API Gateway. 
I need to allow the following URL:

```
/api/v1/get?detail=yes
```

but in the same policy, I also want to deny the following URL.

```
/api/v1/get?detail=no
```

I have looked at policy condition, and can't find a way to put the URL parameter `detail` in the the condition.

Do anyone know the detail on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL parameter this way : `event["queryStringParameters"]['detail']`

So the code should look to something like that :

```
def auth(event, context):
 detail = event["queryStringParameters"]['detail']
 if detail == 'yes':
  return {
        'principalId': principal_id,
        'policyDocument': {
            'Version': '2012-10-17',
            'Statement': [
                {
                    "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                    "Effect": effect,
                    "Resource": resource

                }
            ]
        }
    }
 else:
   raise Exception('Unauthorized')
```